# Функция поиска последовательностей в строке, идущих подряд

Tags: строки, swift, функции, поиск, повторы

Дана строка произвольной длины. Мне нужно найти первую подпоследовательность одинаковых символов, которые идут подряд.

Моя функция (их две, но это две части одной и той же функции) оказалась сложной и громоздкой и не подходила из-за этого. Функция, которая мне нужна, должна быть простой и не слишком длинной.

Описание нужной функции:
"Есть на ходе строка, скажем, «abcbcabcccba»
Нам надо проверить первую букву со второй, потом — две первых с 3-4
Дальше — 1-3 и 4-6 и так далее до string.length/2"

**Пример:**

```
Input : str = "abcabc"
Output : abc

Input : str = "aa"
Output : a

Input : str = "abcbabcb"
Output : abcb

Input : str = "abcbca"
Output : bc

Input : str = "cbabc"
Output : 

Input : str = "acbabc"
Output :
```

**Моя неудачная попытка:**

```
func findRepetition(_ p: String) -> [String:Int] {
    var repDict: [String:Int] = [:]
    var p = p
    while p.count != 0 {
        for i in 0...p.count-1 {
            repDict[String(Array(p)[0..<i]), default: 0] += 1
        }
        p = String(p.dropFirst())
    }
    return repDict
}

var correctWords = [String]()
var wrongWords = [String]()
func getRepeats(_ p: String) -> Bool {
    let p = p
    var a = findRepetition(p)
    for i in a {
        var substring = String(Array(repeating: i.key, count: 2).joined())
        if p.contains(substring) {
            wrongWords.append(p)
            return false
        }
    }
    correctWords.append(p)
    return true
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за пример кода нужной функции!

Comment: а длина то строки какая? найти что-то за квадрат длины легко. Можно и быстрее _правильно_ используя КМП.

Comment: Здравствуйте, длина строки может быть разной

Comment: кхм. ограничение на неё какое? 100 символов или 100 тысяч?

Comment: Об этом в задаче не указано. Поэтому длина любая.

Comment: тогда это невозможно. любая длина не помещается в памяти компьютера.

Comment: Хорошо пусть будет ограничение в 20 символов)

Comment: *Мне нужно найти первую подпоследовательность одинаковых символов, которые идут подряд.* Определите чётко понятие "первая". Например, при входных 'abcbcdbcbcd' ответ 'bc' или 'bcbcd'?

Comment: Akina, спасибо за замечание, исправил! Первой в случае с abcbcdbcbcd будет bc. Но в принципе это не важно, важен сам факт того, что в строке есть какая-то последовательность.

Comment: *это не важно* Это - важно. Осмелюсь сформулировать так: найти тот дубль, координата первого фрагмента которого в строке минимальна, если таковых несколько - то длина которого минимальна. Или наоборот - приоритетом является длина, и только при равенстве - координата?

Comment: И уточните - Вам нужен алгоритм (безотносительно к коду), или Вам нужно отладить свой код (возможно, с изменением алгоритма)?

Comment: Akina, самое главное определить есть ли в строке хоть одна последовательность символов подряд, так что предпочтительнее тот способ, который быстрее.

Comment: Akina, нужно отладить имеющийся код, алгоритм можно менять.

Comment: Регулярное выражение `(.+)\1`  найдёт и [поместит результат в первую подмаску](https://regex101.com/r/EmwyUK/1).